# Lumen 5.3: How to extend validation class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, extending

Validation class has a couple of functions to retrieve errors, how can I extend this class to manipulate array structure of error messages:

```
$v = Validatior::make($input, $rules);
if($v->fails()){
    // Instead of
    print_r($v->errors()->messages());
    // Have
    print_r($v->getErrorsWithMyPreferedStructure());
}
```

I want to add my own function to validation class. Obviousely one of the possible solutions is extending validation class and ... But it's not what I'm searching for. I'm looking for a way to extend validation class via it's own methods, if any!

Comment: why can't you extend it and overwrite the method in the class you are extending it in?

Comment: I personally don't like the idea of creating wrappers of wrappers of ...
Actually I'm trying to utilize laravel native features, first. It would be awesome if I can inject my own trait to this class.

Comment: I gave up, How I can register my wrapper to app container with the same name as laravel validator (`validator`)?